# Local jquery.js not loading in simple html file

Tags: javascript, html

So I was trying to simplify my header and somehow now my local jquery file doesn't load anymore. Other js files load fine but not jquery (i checked with Chrome's DevTools source section).

So I made a test file with a header stripped of most useless things to show you :

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Non-Conformité</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="../bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://{InternalCompanyServer}/nonConforme/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script scr="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row topMargin" header>
        <img class='small-3 columns logo hide-on-print' src="img/logo-fr.png"/>
        <h2 class='small-9 columns' >Formulaire Non-Conformité</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see I tried multiple ways to write the link : Absolute then Relative, I even copied the jquery file to the js folder and tried to link it but no luck.

The foundation.js file just after it loads fine but it gives the :                   "foundation.js:703 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)" Error. Comment if you need more info I didn't think of putting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you put scr forjQuery url instead of src ;)

Edit> just a reflex : https://validator.w3.org/check
Go to direct input, paste you html... and let' go : Line 7, Column 40: there is no attribute "SCR"